# Eloquent: Relationship (JSON) -> HasMany and BelongsTo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento, model

Fala galera tudo bem?

Seguinte, estou com um probleminha relacionado à duas models dentro do meu projeto.

Primeira Model tenho um relacionamento `hasOne`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['phone'];

    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

Na segunda Model faço o relacionamento inverso `BelongsTo`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['user'];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Quando adiciono o `protected $with`, coloco para retornar junto o relacionamento, fica em loop e não processa.

Quem pode me dar uma luz para que isso retorne tanto o relacionamento normal, bem como o inverso?

O meu retorno quando pego a rota de user é:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "email":"joao@gmail.com",
   "phone":{
      "id":1,
      "phone":"123456",
      "user_id":1,
      "user":{
         "id":1,
         "email":"joao@gmail.com",
         "phone":{
            "id":1,
            "phone":"123456",
            "user_id":1,
            "user":{
               "id":1,
               "email":"joao@gmail.com",
               "phone":{
                  "id":1,
                  "phone":"123456",
                  "user_id":1,
                  "user":{
                     "id":1,
                     "email":"joao@gmail.com",
                     "phone":{
                        "id":1,
                        "phone":"123456",
                        "user_id":1,
                        "user":{
                           ... /*infinito*/
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ueh qual é o relacionamento? Tá  confuso se tá perguntando um e falando sobre outro

Comment: Virginio, editei a pergunta colocando o retorno e mostrando o momento em que fica em loop infinito.

Comment: Tira $with primeiro

Answer (score 0):

Sim, porque sempre que você chama user, você chama telefone e sempre que chama telefone chama user, que chama telefone...

Você pode tirar o:

```
protected $with = ['user'];
```

E usar só a relação normalmente, quando precisar usar o telefone:

```
$user->telefone;
```

Caso queira o $with, retire o $with do telefone que parará seu loop, deixe apenas no usuário. Eu particularmente prefiro não usar $with;

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $with = ['user'];
```

tenta rodar sem o `$with` e chamar ele quando desejar

```
$variavel->telefone ou $variavel->telefone()
```